# 'Module' object has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

I'm trying to use the default functions to do background subtraction of a video file.
I'm using Python 2.7 and OpenCV.
I receive this error when using the 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG' module:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG'
```

Now, if I try using the createBackgroundSubtractorMOG() module, I receive the same error.
If I change my code to:

```
bkgnd = cv2.bgsegm.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

I get an error later on that tries to tell me I'm using OpenCV 3.1 (although I'm fairly certain I'm not).

> ```
>  img_sub_gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img_sub, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error:
> ```
>
> /home/odroid/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8000: error:
>   (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Here is the segment of code that is erroring out:

```
bkgnd = cv2.bgsegm.BackgroundSubtractorMOG() 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(True): 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #background subtraction
    img_sub = bkgnd.apply(frame)

    #convert to grayscale
    img_sub_gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img_sub, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #thresholding, forcing to binary image
    ret,threshold1 = cv2.threshold(img_sub_gray_image, LOWER_BOUND, UPPER_BOUND, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In opencv 3 they have changed some names of the functions, you must change:

```
bkgnd = cv2.bgsegm.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

to:

```
cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
```

Another observation is that the result of the apply function is a binary image, so it is not necessary to do the conversion from `RGB` to `gray`. You do not need to use the command: `cv2.cvtColor(img_sub, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: After changing the line to: bkgnd = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()   
I received this error: 
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /home/odroid/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FU_edge_detection_video_HoughLinesP.py", line 60, in <module>
    img_sub_gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img_sub, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/odroid/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8000: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Comment: that got it.  
thank you.  
of course now I have other errors. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This works well..

```
fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
```

P.S: I am using python 3.5 and cv2 version 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

if you are using opencv 4 you should use MOG2 with history, varThreshold, detectShadows parameters

```
cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100,varThreshold=50,detectShadows=True)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation.